# Payment and Media

Tags: isv, developer-console, app-development, developer-productivity

I'm just curious on the Salesforce Partner front, is there any way to obtain physical media for local install (at a fee or otherwise) for any of the developer tools or is it strictly accessed through the development portal?

Also, when paying the revenue shares or other program fees (training etc) is that just done with CC or bank transfer?  Do they accept PayPal transfers?

Thanks!

Comment: Which developer tools are you thinking of? I usually just grab the most recent installer for things like the Data Loader if I need them. They aren't very big.

Answer (score 1):

SFDC doesn't install anywhere, it is a pure-play cloud solution.

You have several options to pay the fees, typically invoice/check or AppExchange Check Out are the solutions folks use.  To the best of my knowledge they do not accept paypal.

Do you have a partner user group in your area?  I am a co-leader for the one here in San Francisco, we have a meeting next week